# Elmah.MVC - MVC 5 ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name id:

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, elmah.mvc

I am receiving an error when trying to render the elmah error logs and using SQL DB.  "http://localhost:5525/elmah" [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: id]
   Elmah.ErrorLogEntry..ctor(ErrorLog log, String id, Error error) in c:\builds\ELMAH-1.2-SP2\src\Elmah\ErrorLogEntry.cs:57
   Elmah.SqlErrorLog.ErrorsXmlToList(XmlReader reader, IList errorEntryList) in c:\builds\ELMAH-1.2-SP2\src\Elmah\SqlErrorLog.cs:365
   Elmah.SqlErrorLog.ErrorsXmlToList(String xml, IList errorEntryList) in c:\builds\ELMAH-1.2-SP2\src\Elmah\SqlErrorLog.cs:332
   Elmah.SqlErrorLog.GetErrors(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, IList errorEntryList) in c:\builds\ELMAH-1.2-SP2\src\Elmah\SqlErrorLog.cs:186
   Elmah.ErrorLogPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in c:\builds\ELMAH-1.2-SP2\src\Elmah\ErrorLogPage.cs:76
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

I have the latest Core Elmah 1.2-SP2 and the latest Elmah.MVC 2.1.2. I installed the Nuget package Elmah.MVC with default web.config settings.

When I configure web.config to log errors to the database the errors are recorded in the database but I can't render the error page. When I don't configure the database the elmah page renders just fine.

```
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Company" />
  </elmah>
```

Decompiling Elmah I see in the constructor where the argument is thrown.

```
if (id == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
      if (id.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException((string) null, "id");
```

All my ErrorId's in the database are populated GUIDs.

I am stumped as to what id is not being passed to the core elmah. Has anyone ran into this before?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the core Elmah code and stepped through to find in SqlErrorLog.cs, method ErrorsXmlToList(XmlReader reader, IList errorEntryList) there is a call to get id which was the parameter missing: string id = reader.GetAttribute("errorId"); I lower cased "errorid" and everything worked. Obviously this is not a good solution because this is core code that everyone works with so I dug deeper.

This led me to look at stored procedure ELMAH_GetErrorsXml. I found in our database we had a lower case "errorid". I updated the stored procedure to select "errorId" and changed the core Elmah back to the original code and of course everything worked.